# anonymous functions javascript, how to access source code?

Tags: javascript

I got some JS Code that gets inside a random Anonymous js function.
I want that code (for example `alert('hello')` ) to dump/alert 
the entire script block/object which it was injected into.

kinda like document.body.innerHTML but for the anonymous function block

result should be like :

```
Function()({ somecode; MyAlert(...) } )()
```

or

```
Try { some code; mycode; } catch(e) { }
```

Comment: Try `alert(arguments.callee);`.

Comment: arguments is undefiend in my case (its try case)

Comment: Is that try-statement inside a function, or is it global code? (When a function code is invoked, an `arguments` object is created for that invocation. So, you are either in global code, or the `arguments` object was manually overwritten.)

Comment: you are accurate, I am sorry if i misled with the word function, it is in global code as a separated script block, not a function.

Comment: By default, once your JavaScript code is injected into a script of a web-page, your code has full-access to the DOM, so you can query the SCRIPT elements of that page, and retrieve the source text of those scripts.

Comment: this script is pushed dynamically from external source, with external context (i.e Flash) so it does not create a script tag.

Comment: I see. I don't know how Flash works, so I'm afraid I won't be able to figure this one out.

Comment: arguments.callee.toString() actually worked for me to get the source of an anonymous function from within the anonymous function. @ŠimeVidas if you post an answer detailing what you know and an example I'd be glad to give you the bounty.

Comment: Use `debugger;` and your _Console_ to explore regions of code during invocation.

Answer (score 3):

1. Mind your terms. **"(browser) script block" literally means script element's code** [by the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-block%27s-type).
   Use "javascript block" ***or*** "javascript object" to mean a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) ***or*** an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).
   Do not create confusing new terms; do read and research.
2. Blocks are not objects; they are language statements.
   Just like you cannot "get the code/variables of current line", **you cannot "get the code/variables of current block"**, try block or not.
3. Stepping back, for now you can **use [`Function.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) to get the function calling your code**:

```js
var mycode = function me(){ if ( me.caller ) alert( me.caller.toString() ); };
(function(){ var some = 'code'; mycode(); })();
// Alert "function(){ var some = 'code'; mycode(); }", even when it is anonymous
```

> Note that you get the whole function's code, not the function block's code which excludes parameters and function name.

4. **Function.caller may be removed in future**, like [`arguments.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/caller). (Both are troubles. What if a cross origin function on the call stack contains private api key code? How should js engines [inline](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/04/automatic-inlining-in-javascript-engines.html) your code?)

   When the time comes, or **when caller is null** (when it is global code), you may still be able to get **textual stacktrace** ([`new Error().stack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/stack)) and **current script element** ([`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript)), but their capabilities are pretty limited.

   You can get a script element's code - if any - with its textContent or innerHTML property.
5. Your question sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  You want to do something that no modern language is meant to do, but never say for what purpose.
   **Try to describe your real problem.**

Comment: Invigorating answer! Thank you very much for all of your insight.

Answer (score 2):

Functions have a `toString()` method. (Yes functions have methods!)

```
var fn = function() { alert('hello') };
fn.toString() // "function() { alert('hello') };"
```

So you can alert it:

```
alert(fn.toString());
```

You can log it to the js console:

```
console.log(fn.toString());
```

Or even write it to the page.

```
document.getElementById('someID').innerHTML = fn.toString();
```

---

However, this won't work for every function in the universe.

```
[].push.toString()
"function push() { [native code] }"
```

Some functions are not implemented with javascript, but in the compiled code of the browser or JS engine. For these environment provided functions, you will get this above less helpful output.

Comment: first of all thanks, I am aware of toString()
second, what if I don't know the name , in my case the dynamic anonymous function's name is unknown for me, (you called it fn) i don't have that name.
is it possible to use something like firstChild().toString()?

Comment: OP stated that the function is anonymous.

Comment: @Šime Vidas how does that change anything? If a variable is a reference to a function object, you can call `toString()` on it. Regardless of how it was declared.

Comment: I edited the comment with this additional information I don't have the name of the function or name of the object

Comment: @AlexWayne We don't know whether we can access the function by name. My guess is that we cannot since the OP emphasized that it's anonymous.

Comment: I guess I'm confused then... How can you ever hope to possibly inspect a thing that you don't know what it is or how to find it?

Comment: Look at the examples in his question. He wants the code to refer to whatever its surrounding context is. I suspect the simple answer is that you can't do it like this.

Comment: well basically after causing a syntax error deliberately, I do know it, but I want to access it from code:
`Source Code:
try { veryWrongJS-Delib-SyntaxError.getValue() ; } catch (e) { "<undefined/>"; }`

i want veryWrongJS-Delib-SyntaxError to be replaced by some command like `alert(EntireScriptBlock.Text)` or `firstChild().toString()` etc...

Comment: I am starting to think that as Javascript cannot execute DOS Commands and is limited, it might not have access to Browser's Script Blocks, anyone with me?
I just used a Breakpoint and looked at local, the object document returns Access is denied!

Comment: @atigertest Your code should have access to the page's SCRIPT elements. Try something like `alert(document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].text)`...

Comment: there is no script element tag ;) (undefined) its a "Browser Script Block"

Answer (score 0):

If you're **not** in strict mode you can go up the stack from something which was referenceable (i.e. a named function expression) using (non-standard) [`.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller)

```
function getFunctionReference(callback) {
    var ref = getFunctionReference.caller;
    if (callback) callback(ref);
    return ref;
}
```

Now you can do things like

```
(function () {
    getFunctionReference(alert);
}());
// alerts the .toString of the IIFE
```

This only works for *functions*, you can't do this on top level code.

---

The best way to explore your code is actually with the *Console*, and you can use the [`debugger;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement or breakpoints to follow exactly what is happening and when.