# how to get the code of an anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```js
function debounce(a, b, c) {
  var d;
  return function() {
    var e = this,
      f = arguments;
    clearTimeout(d);
    d = setTimeout(function() {
      d = null, c || a.apply(e, f)
    }, b), c && !d && a.apply(e, f)
  }
}

var test = debounce(function(x) {
  alert(x);
}, 500)
console.log(test.toString());
```

I would like to get

```
function (x) {alert(x);}
```

but instead I get:

```
function debounce(a, b, c) {....
```

Comment: Based on your example, it can not be, that you get the `debounce` function as a result of the `test.toString()` call, as you call it on assignment and return the inner `function() {}` during the call, therefor `function() { var e = this,... }` becomes the assigned value of `test`.

Comment: `test` is a closure of the inner function. You won't get `alert()` because it's in the value of the `a` variable, it's not the function.

Comment: Please post code with meaningful variable names. That `debounce()` function looks like it was taken from minified code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [anonymous functions javascript, how to access source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905671/anonymous-functions-javascript-how-to-access-source-code)